# PHP POST via AJAX loop through javascript sent object literal

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, post, javascript-objects

Hey all i normally grab the **ajax sent js object literal** by doing this:

```
$_POST['called']
$_POST['chk1']
etc etc...
```

But now i have a problem that i cant seem to find a solution for.

Depending on how many checkboxes are selected, i loop (using js) to see all checked boxes and add them to the js object that ends up looking like this:

```
doBulk = {
   called: "Approved",
   chk0: "1789156857",
   chk2: "5134465673753",
   chk3: "234123554646",
   chk10: "25511545542"        
};
```

Now the **chkXX** can be any number from 0-19 (so 20 check boxes per page). I am sending that just fine to my PHP page but i am unsure on how to go about looping to get the needed data to update the database.

```
$chk1 = $_POST['chk0'];
$chk2 = $_POST['chk1'];
$chk3 = $_POST['chk2'];
$chk4 = $_POST['chk3'];
$chk5 = $_POST['chk4'];
$chk6 = $_POST['chk5'];
$chk7 = $_POST['chk6'];
$chk8 = $_POST['chk7'];
$chk9 = $_POST['chk8'];
$chk10 = $_POST['chk9'];
$chk11 = $_POST['chk10'];
$chk12 = $_POST['chk11'];
$chk13 = $_POST['chk12'];
$chk14 = $_POST['chk13'];
$chk15 = $_POST['chk14'];
$chk16 = $_POST['chk15'];
$chk17 = $_POST['chk16'];
$chk18 = $_POST['chk17'];
$chk19 = $_POST['chk18'];
$chk20 = $_POST['chk19'];
```

I could do a lot of **if than else** to check to see if each has data but there has got to be a better way of doing that?

So if i am doing a bulk mySQL update then i would have to run a query for **each** checkbox that i have a value for above? Is there also a better way of updating all the records that are needed in one swoop?

```
$result = mysql_query("UPDATE userAccount SET Accept = 1 WHERE ID = " . $chk1 . "");
```

Thanks!

**UPDATE**

```
foreach($_POST as $key => $value)
{
    // $key = CHK1-20 
    // $value = XXXXXXXXX
    $dbBuilder = $value . ", " . $dbBuilder;
}

$dbBuilder = '(' . $dbBuilder . ')';

$result = mysql_query("UPDATE userAccount SET Accept = 1 WHERE ID in $dbBuilder");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass in the id's inside an IN SQL Clause. So, for instance you will have:

```
UPDATE userAccount SET Accept = 1 WHERE ID in $idCollection
```

Where $idCollection will be all of the IDs checked, separated by commas and inside parentheses, like so:

```
(1, 2, 3)
```

For the looping, you can iterate through the $_POST array as you would in any other array, and populate this string with the values read.

Hope that helps

Comment: Can you check my OP again, i just updated it with new code and see if i am on the correct track.

Comment: Also, make sure that you are adding the correct id's, since you are iterating the whole $_POST array, you might get values that you're not expecting

Answer (score 0):

```
for ($i=1;$i<=20;$i++){
${'chk'."$i"}=$_POST["chk"."$i"];
}
```

For `UPDATE`, i think you can use `Mysql create procedure` like this

```
$query=mysql_query("CREATE PROCEDURE dorepeat(p1 INT) SET $i = 0; REPEAT SET @i = @i + 1; UPDATE userAccount SET Accept = 1 WHERE ID = ${'chk'."$i"}; UNTIL @i =p1 END REPEAT; END") or (die mysql_error());
$result=mysql_query("CALL dorepeat(20)") or (die mysql_error());
```

EDIT: perhaps this is better without using `CREATE PROCEDURE`.

```
for ($i=1;$i<=20;$i++){
  ${'chk'."$i"}=$_POST["chk"."$i"];
  $exp.=${'chk'."$i"}.',';
} 
$exp=substr($exp,0,-1);
$exp='('.$exp.')'; 

$query=mysql_query("UPDATE userAccount SET Accept = 1 WHERE ID IN '$exp') or (die mysql_error());
```